# How can I do text gradient in CSS without affecting background?

Tags: css, gradient

I would like to use a text gradient on my headers ([this](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect) type of effect, basically). Commonly, this is achieved using png alpha-transparent image over the text. My problem with this solution is that within the header box alpha transparency will also influence the background. So if, for example, I wanted to use a photo as a background of my headers it would look awful. Is there a way around this (at least in some browsers, for starters).

Comment: Could you post a simple demo (http://jsfiddle.net, or http://jsbin.com) of the problem with using the transparent PNG technique? Is it just that the background starts to show through the text?

Comment: The problem is that this type of effect is only any good when you have solid background. I need something that'd work over any background including image backgrounds... I doubt it's possible though :-(

Comment: Are you willing to use JavaScript to do this? The method I'm thinking, users without JS (not *so many* of them) would just get text without the gradient.

Comment: I don't mind, my app is pretty much useless to anyone wihout JavaScript anyway. I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: I was going to write an answer using [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/). Here's a random example showing gradients on text: [http://raphaeljs.com/fonts.html](http://raphaeljs.com/fonts.html) - it will take some effort for me to write the answer up properly. Should I do it?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a way to do this with CSS3 - even the [CSS3 Image Values and Replaced Content Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/), though it contains lots of cool stuff to do with [gradients](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#gradients), only lets you use them where you would be able to use an image, not as a colour.

However, [SVG does let you do this](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Gradients), though taking advantage of it in HTML is a bit of work.  First, create the SVG document with your gradient text in it.  You'll need a gradient:

```
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="heading_gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0); stop-opacity:1"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0); stop-opacity:0.1"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

And some text to apply it to, notice the `fill` attribute:

```
<text x="0" y="100"
    font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="bold"  fill="url(#heading_gradient)" >
    <tspan font-size="100">A Big Heading</tspan>
</text>
```

Then you need to include the SVG in your HTML.

```
<h1>
    <object data="heading-fill.svg" type="image/svg+xml" height="125" width="800">
        A Big Heading
    </object>
</h1>
```

Note that with no SVG support the heading should fall back to the content contained within the object tag and everything *should* be accessible (I haven't checked).  Then set up the CSS so the fallback content should match the SVG and add the background image:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-image: url('daisy-grass-repeating-background.jpg');
}
```

There's [a full example here](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/heading-fill.html), works for me in Firefox 3.6/4, Chromium and Opera 11.01.  It isn't actually very readable, but I'll leave the fine tuning to you ;)  Depending on what browsers you want to support you may need to investigate [`embed` instead of `object`](http://www.alleged.org.uk/pdc/2002/svg-object.html).

Comment: I was going to suggest an SVG solution would be the way to go, but looks like I've been beaten to the punch. +1 for what looks to be a good answer.

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you! Is it possible to inline this piece of svg into the actual page so that I don't have to download one extra document per header? I need to apply this to many different headers on one page.

Comment: @VoY You can only inline if the user has an HTML5 compatible parser (so Firefox 4.0 beta, recent Chrome, Opera 11.50 alpha, IE9).  You might be able to use [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), not sure if it works with `object`, but the only other option for inline is something like [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/), but that adds its own overhead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using it in a few places, you could simply use image replacement:

```
#the-h1
{
  background: url('the-h1.png') no-repeat left top;
  height: 1em;
  text-indent: 9001px;//it's over 9000
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It's not a nice solution as you'll have to make an image for each header you want to replace, but it does have the benefit of being able to enforce a very specific font and style.